Custom Vuetify Build: Minimizing Bundle Size with v-form Only
I'm aiming to optimize my Vue application's bundle size by using only the v-form component from Vuetify. Is it feasible to create a custom Vuetify build that includes solely the v-form component and its essential dependencies?
The company is switching from Vuetify to PrimeVue, but I'm facing a challenge: I need to keep using Vuetify's straightforward form validation. Many of our validation rules are tied to v-form and look like this and works fine
<v-form @submit.prevent="on_submit" validate-on="submit" >
  <v-input v-model="mymodel" :rules="myrules">
    <InputMask v-model="mymodel"  mask="9999" />
   <Button type="submit" >Ok</Button>
  </v-input>
</v-form>


https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/treeshaking
